# Finding the probability of a message encrypting to a given ciphertext

Tags: stream-cipher, notation

I have been watching a crypto course and when they wanted to prove that the OTP is a secure cipher they refer to the probability and what I can't get so far is the understanding of this notation ?

$$P(E_k(m)=c)$$

The probability of a message encrypted to a cipher? How is that?

The general formula is:

$$P(m=m∗|E_k(m)=c)=P(m=m∗)$$

where

- $m$ is the message to be encrypted
- $m∗$ is the message that the attacker guesses
- $c$ is the cipher text
- $E_k$ is the encryption function

Answer (score 1):

Part of your confusion is coming from ignoring the distinction between random variables (e.g., $K$) and their values (e.g., $k$).

Let $p$ be probability distribution of the keys $k\in {\cal K}$ and let $q$ be the probability distribution of the messages $m \in {\cal M},$ assuming both sets $\cal K$ and $\cal M$ are finite. The encryption mapping $E_K(M):=E(K,M)$ is a mapping  $$E:{\cal K} \times {\cal M} \rightarrow {\cal M}$$ 
where we assume the ciphertext space is also $\cal M$ for simplicity. Clearly a well defined cipher would select keys independently of the messages.

Then, using the definitions of conditional probability all quantities can be evaluated. In particular, the ciphertext distribution is directly obtained from the other two distributions since it is completely determined by them.

In general one could have $m$ mapping to $c$ under different key values $k$ and these will need to be summed, each admissible choice weighted by $p(k)q(m).$

Clearly, $P(m=m_1)=q(m_1),$ while $P(m=m_1|E_k(m)=c)$ is $$P(m=m_1|E_k(m)=c)=\frac{\sum_{k\in {\cal K}:E_k(m_1)=c}p(k)q(m_1)}{\sum_{k\in {\cal K},m\in {\cal M}:E_k(m)=c}p(k)q(m)}  $$
where the numerator is taken to be zero in case of an empty sum, and $c$ is fixed.

Comment: """"
where we assume the ciphertext space is also MM for simplicity. Clearly a well defined cipher would select keys independently of the messages. 
""""

how is that you are mapping M to M using K ?  do you mean something like an identity function ?

Comment: Any well defined mapping specifying a unique $c\in {\cal M}$ for any given pair $(k,m)\in {\cal K} \times {\cal M}$ will do. For an additive cipher, such as OTP, $E(k,m)=k+m$.

Answer (score 0):

OTP is perfectly secure against ciphertext-only attack because
$$P(m=m_1|E_k(m)=c)=P(m=m_1)$$
In words: conditional probability that $m_1$ is the plaintext, given that the ciphertext is $c$, is equal to unconditional probability that $m_1$ is the plaintext; that means, knowing the ciphertext reveals absolutely no information about the plaintext.

If you don't know what is conditional probability, you are better take probability theory course first.

Comment: I know what is conditional probability but what I don't get is the term of the the probabilitu  of m =m* given that the encryption of m is c

Answer (score 0):

Define the message space as $\mathcal{M} = \{0,1\}^\ell$ and the key space as $\mathcal{K} = \{0,1\}^\ell$.  Using OTP, the encryption of a message $m \in \mathcal{M}$ is done by xor-ing a one-time uniformly random key $k \in \mathcal{K}$ to get the ciphertext $c = m \oplus k$.

Since $k$ is uniformly random over $\{0,1\}^\ell$, so is $c$.  As a consequence $c$ leaks no information on $m$, thereby proving that OTP is semantically secure.